# Set fixed gutter in Bourbon Neat

Tags: sass, bourbon, neat

By default, Neat uses percentages as the margin-right of each `span-columns` element, but I'm hoping for a fixed `30px` gutter, regardless of the `outer-container` width.

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem and till now cannot figure out how to do this using Neat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution would be to create your own mixin that overrides the Neat gutter.

```
@mixin col-with-gutter( $cols, $gutter ){
    @include span-columns($cols);
    margin-right: $gutter;
}

.half{
    @include col-with-gutter(2, 30px);
}
```

Obviously you would have to do some additional customization if you need to use some of the other `span-columns` features. I suggest you look at the [_span-columns.scss source](https://github.com/thoughtbot/neat/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/grid/_span-columns.scss) to figure out what might work best for you.

Honestly though, I think there is a reason that this functionality isn't built in. In most situations, setting the gutter to `30px` would be detrimental to a responsive design (since the total width of the columns will likely not add up to 100%).

You may have a legitimate reason for wanting exactly `30px`, but if you are not certain you need an exact value it may be worthwhile to reconsider.